# Which linguistic terms, concepts, theories are particularly associated with narrative writing?

Tags: reference-request, written-language, discourse-analysis, framework

Sure, it is obvious, narrative writing is a subject of linguistics. 
Nevertheless, the many topics I browsed through in this site randomly very seldom dealt with narrative structures and processes, it is more about analyzing words, phrases, sounds, sentences, some historical linguistics, but comparatively rare when it is dealt with the analyzing of real literal products.

I would like you to suggest me terms, names etc. all the entities that deals with topics like:

- how can be narratives analyzed,
- what might be universal truths for all kind of narratives,
- the purpose of narratives etc.

Since this is a long topic, I do not expect answers, but hints for further sources and terminology so I had a starting point to investigate myself.

Comment: Basically anything starting with "discourse". But this is pretty broad... and again it doesn't look like you've done much research.

Comment: [Systemic Functional linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemic_functional_linguistics) is an approach that is particularly concerned with narrative structures, though it seems to me the bulk of their work is on writing rather than with actual language. The home page of the [International SFL Association](http://www.isfla.org/Systemics/) also has useful information.

Answer (score 1):

The subdomains of discourse analysis, dialogics (Bakhtin), and the study of narrative discourse markers (Labov & Waletzky) may be of interest.

There is significant literature on this topic, so you can start by googling some of the concepts above.